# Wood hoops vs steel hoops

Tags: acoustic-drumset

Is there any difference, sound wise, of having wood hoops as opposed to steel hoops in your drums? Does the wood affect the sound, or tone of the drum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A short summary:

- flanged hoops: cheap and popular. Their low mass produce rich
  overtones which may lead to a headache when it comes to tuning.
- die-cast hoops: really solid and easier to tune. Some say they
  produce a "focused" sound, maybe because they kill most overtones.
- wood hoops: produce a warmer sound on the drum. Probably in the
  middle of flanged and die-cast.

The hoops DO affect the sound of your drum along with the drumhead and its construction. I understand they are not always made of steel. You can find aluminum and brass as well. I would suggest to try and see which one fits you best.

Some physics:
The sound is a vibration of air masses in the audible spectrum. When you hit a drum, the whole thing vibrates and thus, creates sound. The vibration is induced mainly by the drumhead but the mass of the drum contributes to it. Die-cast hoops dampens this vibration due to their high density. Wood and flanged hoops allow some vibrations through themselves, then contribute differently to the sound.

Comment: Could you give more details about your answer? I still don't how the material affects the sound.

Comment: Well that depends on how deep you want to go into the subject. But I can try... do you have an specific question?

Comment: What is the science behind how the wood/metal changes the sound

Comment: I used to know a couple of things about vibration mechanics. The sound is a vibration of air masses in the audible spectrum. When you hit a drum, the whole thing vibrates and thus, creates sound. The vibration is induced mainly by the drumhead but the mass of the drum contributes to it. Die-cast hoops dampens this vibration due to their high density. Wood and flanged hoops allow some vibrations through themselves, then contribute differently to the sound.

Comment: You are wellcome. I will include last comment into the answer so you can mark it as correct ;)